# Why can't I get value fckeditor. done after their code example [Javascript]

Tags: asp.net, javascript, fckeditor

I wonder why I can't get value from FCKEditor with this javascript? I work with asp.net so I know the controls get different names, mine is in a placeholder and in a usercontrol. How should I approach it to find the FCKEditor?

thx

```
function test()
{
    var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('FCKeditor1');
    var pageValue = oEditor.GetHTML();

    alert(pageValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the mark-up from the the ASP.NET page too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but the problem is that using this approach you can not have this function in external JavaScript file. It has to be inline in your asp.net page.

```
function test()
{
    var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(<%= FCKeditor1.ClientID%>);
    var pageValue = oEditor.GetHTML();

    alert(pageValue);
}
```

Comment: i tried that but my fckeditor is located in a usercontrol so the fckeditor is not on intellicense if you know what i mean? it just wont work writing like that..

Comment: put this function in your user control. You can still access the java script function.

Comment: to get around the 'inline' in the asp.net page problem, you can do a server side include on the external javascript file

Answer (score 0):

```
FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('<%=FCKeditor1.ClientID%>')
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET generates different IDs to the ones you use based on their position within the DOM. You should use the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720435(VS.71).aspx) from within the client code to get at the actual ID, but without seeing the mark-up I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code an it work

```
FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_FCKeditor1');
```

i tried

```
FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('<%=FCKeditor1.ClientID%>')
```

thing that last wont work cause i got page - usercontrol - fckeditor
so the intellesence wont show the fckeditor. i would like to make it work with the last one
so i dont have to put the "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_FCKeditor1"

Comment: Please use comments or Edit your answer to further discuss the problem.